# Process the bash output with color code

Tags: bash, colors

I have a Mac App ([CodeRunner](https://coderunnerapp.com)) that executes a script in login mode and shows the output in a window.
In error condition, it returns the code with escape characters to make the output hard to read.

[image]

Is there a way to process the color code? Is there a filter to remove the color code?

Comment: Are the control characters (escapes) still in the output or have those been stripped by something?

Comment: @Etan Reisner: They are all there, the attached picture is the screen capture from the output window.

Comment: The color codes are `\E[31m` where `\E` is an escape. That output shows the non-escape part of the strings. I assume the escapes are there but they might not be at that point already. Whatever the program is that is generating that output probably needs a bug filed against it to have it not output color codes when not outputting to a terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Mac OS X, I used [stderred](https://github.com/sickill/stderred) library.

```
#export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="/LOCATION_OF_THE_LIB/libstderred.dylib${DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES:+:$DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES}"
```

Removing this library setup shows the strings without the code.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question, the easiest way to control color in bash (or any terminal that supports them) is with ANSI escape sequences. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

blue='\e[0;34m'         # ${blue}
green='\e[0;32m'        # ${green}
nc='\e[0m'              # ${nc} (no color - disables previous color selection)

printf "${blue}This text is blue, ${green}this is green${nc}\n"

exit 0
```

There are a number of complete references for the ANSI sequences available on the web, but for basic colors, the following is generally sufficient:

```
black='\e[0;30m'        # ${black}
blue='\e[0;34m'         # ${blue}
green='\e[0;32m'        # ${green}
cyan='\e[0;36m'         # ${cyan}
red='\e[0;31m'          # ${red}
purple='\e[0;35m'       # ${purple}
brown='\e[0;33m'        # ${brown}
lightgray='\e[0;37m'    # ${lightgray}
darkgray='\e[1;30m'     # ${darkgray}
lightblue='\e[1;34m'    # ${lightblue}
lightgreen='\e[1;32m'   # ${lightgreen}
lightcyan='\e[1;36m'    # ${lightcyan}
lightred='\e[1;31m'     # ${lightred}
lightpurple='\e[1;35m'  # ${lightpurple}
yellow='\e[1;33m'       # ${yellow}
white='\e[1;37m'        # ${white}
nc='\e[0m'              # ${nc} (no color - disables previous color selection)
```

**Note:** always reset the color to default at the end of a string with `${nc}` (`'\e[0m'`) to prevent continuation of the color after your script finishes. Lastly, if using `echo`, you must use `echo -e` to process the ANSI codes.

**Note2:** since you are seeing the codes and not the color, you have several possibilities (1) you are using `echo` without the `-e` option to allow proper interpretation of the codes (or something similar); or (2) the terminal you are using lacks color capability (though that is doubtful, as just about all modern terminals are VT based with default color handling available).

As suggesting by the comments below, you can also set color with `tput` (`setab #` for background and `setaf #` for foreground).

Comment: His output already has the escape codes (or part of them, anyway); he wants them to either be interpreted correctly or be removed from the output.

Comment: Suggesting using `tput` to determine the correct codes for the current terminal is probably a good idea.